# How do you enable Perl on Ubuntu with Apache2

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, perl

I have installed ubunutu witha apache on my pc and everything works great except: I don't know  how to enable perl, everything I have tried either gave me a server error or gave me a 403 for the perl scripts.

Please tell me how to enable Perl. Thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about mod_perl or CGI scripts? Please add some details, what you tried, exact error message, config etc.

Comment: Im not sure what CGI is, but I want to be able to run perl scripts on .pl files, I am receiving the following error `[24/Jul/2012:20:24:51 -0400] "GET /test.pl HTTP/1.1" 403 410 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_4) AppleWebKit/536.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Safari/536.19"` and I used: `<Directory /var/www/>
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .pl
</Directory>` in my apache.conf file I am not sure whats wrong, please help me out, I have no other details.

Comment: @rgbc: It will be better and more readable to include your last comment in your question.

Answer (score 1):

does your script have #!/usr/bin/perl as its first line?